# Use a different table prefix for cakephp session database

Tags: php, database, session, cakephp

I'd like to use a different table prefix for my session database. So, in my config file I have my table prefix set as "pre1_", but I'd like my sessions to use a table with the prefix "pre2_" -- is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the prefix in the `database.php` config file to the prefix I wanted my sessions table to have, then in each model set the `$table_prefix` property to the prefix those required. Seems a little weird, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I remarked the line in my model so it would not be executed;

```
//    public $tablePrefix = 'cc_';
```

Then, in my AppController.php beforeFilter I added

```
$this->modelname->tablePrefix=$this->Auth->user('company_prefix').'_';
```

In my users table of my authorization I have a field called company_prefix which is prepended to certain tables that are unique to that user.

I would love to see more on this subject.

I get a lot of `'Indirect modification of overloaded property DifferentController::$Modelname has no effect'`

So I am looking for a way of doing this only when the model is added or the default of a controller. I don't want a `beforeFilter()` for every controller, so I think I will have to do some sort of `isset()`

Comment: The only thing I've come up with so far was to implement the session handler interface in a new model, then change the prefix in that. I might've been on the right track with that, but I had no success.

Answer (score 0):

For a 'company' prefix in Cakephp 2.1 - public $tablePrefix in the model and setting the tablePrefix in the controller, here is what I am doing and it is too many lines of code (one line of code per table that has a prefix per user) but it is all I can do right now.

Modela.php:

```
public $tablePrefix = 'anything_';
```

Modelb.php:

```
public $tablePrefix = 'anything_';
```

Modelc.php:

```
public $tablePrefix = 'anything_';
```

then in the public function beforeFilter() of the AppController

```
if (isset($this->Modela->tablePrefix)) {$this->Modela->tablePrefix = $this->Auth->user('company_code').'_'; }
if (isset($this->Modelb->tablePrefix)) {$this->Modelb->tablePrefix = $this->Auth->user('company_code').'_'; }
if (isset($this->Modelc->tablePrefix)) {$this->Modelc->tablePrefix = $this->Auth->user('company_code').'_'; }
```

I don't get the 'overloaded property' error this way, but in my schema, all my users have a valid company code. I also have for example the 'users' table is shared for all users (although only admins can get to a user record other than the logged in user)

However, I find this rather cumbersome, and am interested in a means that would not require every single model that is to be segregated by the model's $tablePrefix company_code setting to be defined as a line of code in the AppController. The point at which I really want to set the tablePrefix for a model is the instant I reference

```
$this->loadModel("Modelb");
```

But I spent 45 minutes playing with modelb.php in the Model directory and was not able to do much with the $tablePrefix property. When a model is instantiated or referenced, I should know, for those tables that need a $tablePrefix property, the required prefix, but I was not able to set the property dynamically at that point. (a dynamic static property? sounds like the wrong approach)

So, even though this works, I don't like it. It feels like I am using Fortran methods in a Lisp program.

Answer (score 0):

within ModelasController.php:

```
$this->loadModel("Modelb");
$this->Modelb->tablePrefix = $this->Auth->user('company_code');
```

is the proper way to use a second company coded model, and I don't need the beforeFind logic.

So only the AppController has a line for every possible model in the beforeFilter to set the tablePrefix, just like above, using the php function isset to detect the model.

But when I pull a secondary model into a controller with the loadModel, I immediately follow that now by setting the tablePrefix to the company code, which I can get to in the controller. This reaches into the model object and overrides the tablePrefix static property.